# redirect access phpmyadmin to another page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I allow my host server for restricted IP, but when another IP access to /phpmyadmin, they always get error

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

Error 403

I want to change my page forbidden access for /phpmyadmin. redirect back to home page, so only allow IP can access the page.

I try .htaccess on my root folder, but still can't change anything the page when I access fwww.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin

Comment: Show us what you tried, please. // Maybe the simplest way to achieve this would be to specify a PHP script as the 403 ErrorDocument via .htaccess inside the phpMyAdmin base folder, and have that script simply issue a redirect back to your base domain.

Answer (score 0):

for my case, I change alias from httpd-conf for default /phpmyadmin to another address, and now address for /phpmyadmin can't reachable.

for me it's enough because, guest user cant access the default address.

Comment: how to close this topic.